# Добавить два ключа с одним и тем же названием

Tags: python, dict

Мне нужно чтобы мой словарь содержал два ключа одинакового названия, например

```
_dict = dict()
_dict['key'] = 204
_dict['key'] = 521 # Знаю, что просто теперь 204 заменится на 521, 
#а мне надо так, чтобы было два ключа `key` 
#один из которых имеет значение 204 а другой 521
```

EDIT:

Мне нужно отправить POST запрос с такой `data`-ой

```
q1881247:1_:flagged: 0
q1881247:1_:flagged: 0
q1881247:1_:sequencecheck: 1
q1881247:1_answer: 0
q1881247:2_:flagged: 0
q1881247:2_:flagged: 0
```

Comment: И что должно вывести `print(_dict['key'])`, если в словаре будут дубликаты ключа `key`?

Comment: Не знаю, первое что найдет

Comment: не ясна практическая цель вашего вопроса. храните оба значения в _одном_ ключе в виде кортежа или списка. Два одинаковых ключа в словаре у вас не получится сделать.

Comment: @Kaznachei если первое, что найдёт, тогда вам нужно только одно значение, а это именно то, что стандартная реализация словаря делает.

Comment: Для POST Запроса. Он выглядит так `q1881247:1_:flagged: 0
q1881247:1_:flagged: 0
q1881247:1_:sequencecheck: 1
q1881247:1_answer: 0
q1881247:2_:flagged: 0
q1881247:2_:flagged: 0`

Comment: Не очень ясна связь между POST-запросом и словарем.

Comment: в питоне последнее добавленное значение сохраняется в ключе. то, что вы хотите сделать - невозможно. Есть выход -  хранить значения в списке например.

Comment: Значит, вам не нужен словарь. Вам просто нужно формировать строку с запросом и не мучиться с одинаковыми ключами.

Answer (score 0):

Храните все значения с для одного ключа в списке или кортеже.

Например, так:

```
mydict = {}

def addval(d: dict, a, b):
    if d.setdefault(a, [b]) != [b]:
        d[a].append(b)

addval(mydict, 'key1', 500)
print(mydict) #{'key1': [500]}
addval(mydict, 'key1', -500)
print(mydict) # {'key1': [500, -500]}
```